# Parallels 18 already supports Windows x64 on M1?

Tags: windows, parallels-desktop

I downloaded parallels 18 today on my MBP M1 PRO, to my surprise I found that I can run X64/X86 programs directly on the Windows 11 ARM VM, which I don't understand how they do it.

I can run Intellij Idea x64 smoothly, even my games.

I wonder if we can do the same thing for x64/x86 linux ? Is it already supported ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not Parallels 18 as such that supports that. It is a generic feature in Windows 11 for ARM.

It works in principle similar to how Rosetta 2 on the Mac works. Although with a different set of limitations, and a slightly different performance profile.

For Linux you cannot use Microsoft's software for running Intel programs on ARM. However, Apple has made their Rosetta 2 software available for running Intel programs inside Linux on Mac hardware.

Note that this still requires you to install an ARM version of Linux, but you will be able to run your Intel Linux programs on that system. Similar to how you have installed Windows 11 for ARM that is capable of running Intel softare.

As far as I know, Parallels haven't made the process of using Rosetta 2 inside Linux inside Parallels super user friendly yet - but it will probably come soon.

For now you can use Apple's generic instructions here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/virtualization/running_intel_binaries_in_linux_vms_with_rosetta

And you can find helpful software (does not require Parallels) to get it working in practice here:

https://github.com/diddledani/macOS-Linux-VM-with-Rosetta